# 802.1x wired authentication failed

Tags: ethernet, openwrt, wpa-supplicant, 802.1x

I have this problem: I live in a university dorm room with an ethernet port because the campus wifi doesn't reach. So, together with the network administrator that was on board with this, I used an openWRT router to create an access point inside my room. It worked for a couple of months until the power went out and now I can't reconnect with the exact same configuration. This is my wpa_supplicant file:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=root
ap_scan=0
network={
        key_mgmt=IEEE8021X
        eap=PEAP
        pairwise=CCMP TKIP
        identity="myUniEmail"
        password="myUniPassword"
        phase1="peapver=0"
        phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

And what I get is this:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
eth0.1: Associated with 01:80:c2:00:00:03
WMM AC: Missing IEs
eth0.1: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
eth0.1: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
eth0.1: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25
eth0.1: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 25 (PEAP) selected
eth0.1: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=0 subject='C=IT, ST=emilia romagna, L=Bologna, O=ALMA MATER STUDIORUM - Università di Bologna, OU=Cesia, CN=almawifi.unibo.it' hash=ce505b0c76f06f20ad7e4cafef889f5e2d098d8e9e6253fdd5d7258c8a579e45
eth0.1: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=1 subject='C=NL, ST=Noord-Holland, L=Amsterdam, O=TERENA, CN=TERENA SSL CA 3' hash=beb8efe9b1a73c841b375a90e5fff8048848e3a2af66f6c4dd7b938d6fe8c5d8
eth0.1: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
```

Any idea on how can I get this working again? Again, I know for a fact that this configuration worked before and nothing has changed on the network.

Comment: It seems to be missing `anonymous_identity="myUniEmail"`

Comment: It should also be, I think, `password=hash:yyyy` where yyyy is `echo myUniPassword | tr -d '\n' | iconv -t utf16le | openssl md4`

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I repeat, I haven't done anything like that before and it worked just fine. Also, what do you mean by your first post?

Comment: Modifications to the wpa_supplicant file. Test them out.

Comment: vi  or nano /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf and restarting it. I am mobile right now, won't be able to help further.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro tried. same output.